# Rebind Microsoft Sculpt Mobile Mouse (Windows Key)

Tags: mouse, key-binding

using the [microsoft sculpt mobile mouse](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/sculpt-mobile-mouse), by downloading the [Mouse and Keyboard Center](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center) , i can rebind the mouse keys, but the WINDOWS key i can't change it, and that is the only key i may(and want) to rebind because i have it (twice) on the keyboard, and i can't find an option to change it, am i missing something? Or is there any way to bypass this limitation

[image]

i found that the keys are saved here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IntelliPoint\ModelSpecific\5025\EventMapping\4`

but i've been trying to change the [4](4 is middle mouse button) but i didn't found any for the windows key

Comment: probably @techie007 ... kinda stupid, and makes me regret have bought it, but i don't need the official way of things too ;)

Comment: They don’t even sanction using the Windows key as a modifier; it is “reserved” for use by Windows. `¬_¬` You may be better off just getting a $5 (USD) wireless mouse from eBay with navigation buttons on the side. It is a lot more useful. As for remapping the button, you can try using a macro program or something that can show key/button presses to see if it has a scan-code or something, in which case, you should be able to remap it like any other key or button. However, I suspect that it probably has a special hardware line that is only detectable by the proprietary drivers/software. `:-|`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'd love to find a way to remap that windows button....

Comment: @EricB. for Windows I did not... the key from the mouse is not a key that has a macro like feature, it's actually emulating a keyboard with the window Key, so there is no setting saying "window key" the you can change, on Linux I found that I can bind keys and name the device I'm binding so I can change the window Key from the mouse "keyboard"  without messing with my keyboard, but on windows I found no way of doing that especially without "breaking"  every keyboard

Answer (score 3):

After a bunch of digging around, I finally found a link on [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/95154-side-button-on-microsoft-sculpt-comfort-mouse/) with precisely this issue.  I've tried the suggestion and it seems to work well.

Here is my autohotkey script that I am using to rebind my Windows button to be the back button, and the back button to be a forward button.

```
RWin::Send {Browser_Back}
XButton1::Send {Browser_Forward}
```

Comment: Does this bind the Windows key only on the mouse? Or also the one one keyboard?

Comment: @zoagli Just the windows key on the mouse

Comment: Yep, it works for me too. I only have a left Windows key, so rebinding the right Windows key only affects the mouse. BTW I know about AutoHotKey, but I used KeyTweak instead.

Answer (score 3):

So as said a few times in other answers, the window button is actually sending a keyboad event of the right window key. Now I assume most of us don't even have a right window key, if so you probably only use the left one anyway.

To deactivate the right window key we need to add a Binary value in regedit.
Add it manually or save the below text in a .reg file. Works great for me!
**Don't forget to reboot after.**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,5C,E0,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: I disabled the mouse button with this, but I want to function as an extra mouse button. Like in winapi clicking the side button (back button) sends code of `WM_XBUTTONDOWN` (in winapi) with code of x val 1, the blue windows button should also send `WM_XBUTTONDOWN` but with x val of 2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx Do you know how to instead of disabling this mosue button - to make it send the button 5 message? (left mouse button is button 1 msg, right is button 2, middle is button 3, then the side is buon 4, and the windows key should be button 5)

Comment: I explained my comment better and with a graphic here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/scult-ergonomic-mouse-from-a-winapi-prespective/e829bfe2-bc0e-4a17-ac97-9f0221b2a876?tm=1447393759842

Comment: If you want the mouse's and keyboard's right Windows button to instead be a **Forward** button, as opposed to disabling it entirely, you can make the scancode map do that too. I used [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases) to remap from `Special: Right Windows (E0_5C)` to `Web: Forward (E0_69)`. This resulted in a scancode map of `"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,69,e0,5c,e0,00,00,00,00`. The effect is similar to the AutoHotKey approach, except you don't need another program always running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Sucks that it was done this way.

I just got a sculpt keyboard and mouse (ergonomic) to replace my 5000 series.

I love back and forward buttons on the mouse for browsing and they are also useful in other application scenarios.

It should have been another mouse button which would have been configured to send a keyboard command if desired.

Because its not it can't be re-mapped without effecting the right Windows key.

Its funny that you can change this easily on linux but not Windows without altering how the keyboard input works...

I am not sure why it was logical for a mouse device to send keyboard events and I found out they both are just generic human input devices.

This means their class is neither mouse or keyboard and the usb receiver essentially translates the events it receives and dispatched interrupts for keyboard or mouse events on a virtual device.

This further supports that the button could be remapped however its just not allowed in the software that Microsoft has available and im honestly not sure why.

I dont like needing auto hot keys and while I don't have a general solution for everyone it should be known the driver for the mouse can be modified to send a different event and then you wouldn't need auto hot keys.

You would then only need to select a different mouse  model under the Microsoft software and then remap whatever mouse key you had the driver dispatch for the signal which is received from the mouse when that button is physically pressed (which is different from what is received by the usb receiver for the right Windows key).

I used the 5000 profile and the same event it supplied for the forward button and it works fine.

Hope that made sense!

Comment: Hi there Jay, it didn't make sense to me :( I added the registry entry as mentioned by K_Rol above and I am not able to remap my button still :( Im using the scult ergo mouse as well. :(

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center 10.4.137.0 on Windows 7 with a Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse. Hopefully these steps also work with the Sculpt Mobile Mouse.

1. Install [Mouse and Keyboard Center](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center).
2. Launch the program from the Start Menu or Mouse control panel item.
3. If the program initially shows you another device besides your mouse (like a keyboard), click on the picture of your mouse on the left or right edge of the window to select it.
4. Click `Windows Button`.
5. Click `View all commands`.
6. Select the command you want the mouse's Windows button to perform, like `Browser Forward`, a key combination, or just disable the button entirely. Changes take effect immediately.

---

[image: Mouse and Keyboard Center screenshot of changing Windows Button action]